# How to get specific selected related products in magento2

Tags: magento2

```
   if((bool)$checkoutQuote->getInstallmentEnabled()==true&&$allRelatedProductIds->getSelect()->getId()!=null){
```

As the title, i am trying to get the related product that the customer has selected and it cannot be null. However, this condition has been put into a beforeSave() function in a customplugin.php so that it will check the condition before add to cart.

Comment: $selectedProductId = (int)$this->request->getParam('Related Products', 0);

Comment: Is that there is something like this to get the related product?